# Setting ENLARGE_PAGE_SIZE for pdf in birt report

Tags: java, dynamic, report, birt

I am generating BIRT report dynamically using DE. While rendering the pdf I would like to set the ENLARGE_PAGE_SIZE and orientation to Landscape. Can any one help me plzzzzzz.......

Thanks in advance !!! :) :D

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing your rendering, set the render option like:

renderOption.setOption( PDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW,
                new Integer( PDFRenderOption.ENLARGE_PAGE_SIZE ) );

If you are using the de api to create  the report, set the master page to landscape:
designHandle.getMasterPages().get(0).setProperty("orientation", "landscape");

Jason

Comment: Thanks Jason! This was more helpful! Now I have to get more fields (about 45) from the DB using BIRT. The 45 fields are not able to accommodate page although it is in landscape mode. Could you please provide me some more options for DE API to accommodate all my fields! This will have a great help to me. Thanks in advance !!!